# Where is the regex expression getting wrong?

Tags: java, regex

I have to check for strings such that the string can contain alphanumeric characters and/or underscore(_). I wrote the pattern expression in Java below. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
String pattern = "(\\w*)(_*)(\\d*)";
```

Example of strings that match are hello123_, hi_12hello, bhushu, 12_, 23, etc.
Suggest changes on the pattern expression.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: Please give some examples of strings you do want to match, and examples of strings you don't want to match.

Comment: Just test for `\\w`, it includes `\\d` and `_`.

Comment: the `\w` group is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so not sure why you need the rest of the pattern anyway

Comment: If you think that this regular expression doesn't work, please give an example where you expected it to match but it didn't (and/or expected it not to match but it did)

Answer (score 5):

Your current pattern matches

- Zero or more characters from `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- Followed by zero or more underscores
- Followed by zero or more digits

So it works for any of the examples that you give, since the first point here matches them all, and the others can be empty.

However, you can express the pattern more simply as:

```
String pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9_]*";
```

or

```
String pattern = "\\w*";
```

i.e. just the first group from your current expression.

See the Javadoc for [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Both regexes also match the empty string, which might lead to unexpected results as well. Perhaps `"\\w+"` would make more sense, depending on what the OP actually wants to do...

Comment: @TimPietzcker agreed, but since OP is not being forthcoming with his exact requirements...